# How to read sms

Tags: c#

May I know how to read an SMS from my mobile phone and display on the PC?The mobile phone is connected to the PC via the data cable. I need to know how to code it using C#. I use nokia .

Comment: And which Nokia model can you program in C#?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the [Nokia PC Connectivity API](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Tools_Docs_and_Code/Tools/Plug-ins/Enablers/PC_Connectivity_API/Features.xhtml). This [post](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?p=579372) may help.